# Put list of integers into a variable then use it in select statement

Tags: mysql

I have a list of integers, that I want to use to generate a list of customers.
I want to put the list into a variable, so I can use the list multiple times.
How can this be done?

I have tried this -

```
set @CustIds = '001,002,003';
select * from customer 
where customer_id in (@CustIds); -- NOTE: customer_id is an integer
```

This is not working.
How can I declare my list of customer ids to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
set @CustIds = '001,002,003';
select * from customer 
where find_in_set(customer_id, @CustIds) > 0;
```

Comment: Kittens dying somewhere